# Do not show restricted data in the table?

Tags: reactjs, html-table

how can I limit the data I get in a column in a table. So after a certain character, the table shows "transact ...".

Data I received: List actions
show up to 15 characters on the table. Show it as "..." after 15 characters.

How can I do this with react?

[image]

Comment: [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) the text and add `...`?

Comment: How do I do this with reactjs?
Is there an example on the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this. One using JavaScript and the other using CSS

**Using CSS: (Recommended Way)**
Css has a property called `text-overflow: ellipsis;` this property cuts off the text for **fixed-width** html elements and adds `...` at the end. Make sure to set `max-width` and `overflow: hidden`

See in the snippet below:

```css
.text-overflow-test td {
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table class="text-overflow-test" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>This is short text</td>
      <td>This is short text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is very long long long very long long long very long long long text</td>
      <td>This is very long long long very long long long very long long long text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Using Javascript:**
Check if length is greater then 15. Slice the text and add ... at the end.

```js
const data = [
 {text: "less than 15"},
 {text: "This text is a lot more than just 15 characters"},
 {text: "15   characters"},
]

const slicer = (text) => text.length > 15 ? text.slice(0,15) + '...' : text

const slicedData = data.map(obj => {
 return {
  text: slicer(obj.text)
 }
})

console.log(slicedData)
```

The javascript way is not recommended as it alters the actual data that you are passing to the table resulting in loss of information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css property `text-overflow` for this case.

```css
.long-cell {
  max-width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <th>Col 1</th>
  <th>Col 2</th>
  <th>Col 3</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Short text</td>
    <td>Short text</td>
    <td class="long-cell">Longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Short text</td>
    <td>Short text</td>
    <td class="long-cell">Longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Short text</td>
    <td>Short text</td>
    <td class="long-cell">Longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext longtext</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```